# Why are eevee and cycles so different

Tags: rendering

So a blender newbie here,
I was following up a tutorial and I noticed a thing in EEVEE and cycles viewport render,
Where EEVEE viewport looks terribly different than CYCLES
[image: CYCLES VIEWPORT][image: EEVEE VIEWPORT]

So is it normal or did I mess up some EEVEE settings,
Any help will be appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Typically differences are much subtler - until you use a cycles only, or eevee only feature. For example if one of your materials emits light, it will emit it only in Cycles. If you use shader to RGB node, it can change the material output drastically, but it will change it only for Eevee, where it works...

Comment: Seems like it's only the ground plane material that's causing trouble. If you share your file, we can very quickly identify the problem: https://blend-exchange.com/